# Total sales amount for customers in cities

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL statement that shows the total sales amount for customers in cities who have done at least 2 orders. But let say I only want to show the the city/cities where someone has done at least 2 orders, and that there are two customers living in this city/cities, so what I want to do is to pick out the city/cities where a customer has made at least 2 orders, but then show the total sales amount for both the customers living in this city, even if the other customer has only made one order, how is that done, should there be a comparison statement for the COUNT-operation to be able to show the sales amount for all the customers in the cities, if so - how is it stated?

```
SELECT c.CityName, SUM(p.Price * o2.Orderquantity) AS 'TotalSalesAmount'
FROM Customers c, Order1 o1, Orderrader o2, Products p,
(SELECT o1.CustomerNr 
FROM Order1 o1
GROUP BY o1.CustomerNr 
HAVING COUNT(o1.CustomerNr) >= 2)
AS a WHERE c.CustomerNr = a.CustomerNr AND c.CustomerNr = o1.CustomerNr
AND o1.Ordernr = o2.Ordernr AND o2.Productnr = p.Productnr
GROUP BY c.CityName
```

The structures of the tables I work with look like:

```
'Customers' has the columns: CustomerNr, City Name
'Order1' has columns: Ordernr, CustomerNr
'Order2' has columns: Ordernr, Productnr, Order quantity
'Products' has columns: ProductNr, Price
```

Sample data: Sample data for the table 'Customers':

```
- CustomerNr  CityName:
- 01109       New York
- 01999       Los Angeles
- 20090       New York
```

Sample data for 'Order1':

```
- Ordernr  CustomerNr
- 1306     01109
- 1307     01109
- 1308     20090
```

Sample data for 'Order2':

```
- OrderNr   ProductNr  Order quantity:
- 1306      15-116     3
- 1306      46-701     2
- 1307      15-96      1
- 1308      17-91      1
```

(etc...)

Sample data for 'Products':

```
- ProductNr  Price:
- 15-116     44.00
- 15-96      28.50
- 46-701     3000.00
- 17-91      200.00
```

etc...

According to the SQL statement and sample data above, the desired result I want is:

```
- CityName  TotalSalesAmount:
- New York   6360.50
```

Comment: What would the desired output look like with your sample data?

Comment: Check my edited post above. :-)

Comment: How did you manage to get 6260.50? Did you mean 6360.50?

Comment: Haha yes, I ment 6360.50. :)

Comment: what is the relationship between `Orders1` and `order2` table

Comment: In Order2, the ordernr refers to the ordernr in Order1.

Comment: @ecinna - No that doesn't make sense. If i join `Orders1` and `order2` on `ordernr` then i will get 4 orders for `1306` which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a subquery. I know this looks a bit nasty but must be working.

**Turns out that you have a duplicate Ordernr (1306) for the same CustomerNr in your Order1 example. I am assuming that this might not be the case in your real data.**

```
SELECT c.CityName, 
(Select SUM(order2.quantity * products.Price) from order1 
INNER JOIN Customers On Customers.CustomerNr=order1.CustomerNr 
INNER JOIN Order2 ON Order2.Ordernr=Order1.Ordernr 
INNER JOIN Products ON Products.ProductNr=Order2.ProductNr 
WHERE Customers.CityName=c.CityName) AS 'TotalSalesAmount'
FROM Order1 o1
INNER JOIN (SELECT o1.CustomerNr 
        FROM Order1 o1 
        GROUP BY o1.CustomerNr 
        HAVING COUNT(o1.CustomerNr) >= 2
       ) AS a ON o1.CustomerNr = a.CustomerNr 
INNER JOIN Order2 o2 ON o1.Ordernr = o2.Ordernr 
INNER JOIN Customers c ON o1.CustomerNr = c.CustomerNr
INNER JOIN Products P ON o2.ProductNr = P.ProductNr
GROUP BY c.CityName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
SELECT CityName, SUM(quantity * Price) AS TotalSalesAmount
FROM (
    SELECT c.CityName, p.ProductNr, b.quantity, p.Price, (b.quantity * p.Price) as total --, SUM(b.quantity * p.Price) AS TotalSalesAmount
    FROM customers c
        INNER JOIN order1 a ON c.CustomerNr = a.CustomerNr
        INNER JOIN order2 b ON a.Ordernr = b.Ordernr
        INNER JOIN products p ON b.Productnr = p.ProductNr
    GROUP BY c.CityName, p.ProductNr, b.quantity, p.Price
    ) AS cust
GROUP BY CityName
HAVING COUNT(cityname) >= 2
```

Comment: I really need a simplified code, because that seems to be far more code than necessary. I know that you only should need to add some comparison of some kind to my SQL statement to make sure all customers are counted in the total sales amount for the same city. But I'm not sure how to state this comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT c.CityName,
       Sum(o2.Orderquantity * p.Price) Total_sale
FROM   Customers C
       JOIN (SELECT o.CustomerNr
             FROM   Order1 o
             GROUP  BY o.CustomerNr
             HAVING Count(o.CustomerNr) >= 2) su
         ON c.CustomerNr = su.CustomerNr
       JOIN Customers c1
         ON c1.CityName = c.CityName
       JOIN Order1 o1
         ON o1.CustomerNr = c1.CustomerNr
       JOIN Order2 o2
         ON o2.Ordernr = o1.Ordernr
       JOIN Products P
         ON o2.ProductNr = P.ProductNr
GROUP  BY c.CityName
```

Comment: You don't need an orderID in neither Order1 nor Order2, since in Order1 the primary key is the ordernr, and in Order2 the ordernr AND the productnr, together, work as primary key. So I know I'm not suppose to solve the question like that.

Comment: @ecinna Then how ordernr `1306` is repeated in `Order1` table

Comment: Ok, the sample data is now corrected because that was my bad, just to make things clear, but I hope you can still see the point I'm seeking?

Answer (score 0):

I have interpretted your question as " I need the sum of ALL sales by city, for any city where a single customer has placed more than one order."

```
select 
    c.City,
    SUM(p.Price * o2.Orderquantity) AS 'TotalSalesAmount' 
from
    (select c.City
    from @t_Customers c
    inner join @t_Order1 o1
        on o1.CustomerNr = c.CustomerNr
    group by c.City
    having count(c.City) > 1) as ct
    inner join @t_Customers c
        on c.City = ct.City
    inner join @t_Order1 o1
        on o1.CustomerNr = c.CustomerNr
    inner join @t_Order2 o2
        on o2.OrderNr = o1.Ordernr
    inner join @t_Products p
        on p.ProductNr = o2.ProductNr
group by c.City
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ci.city_name,pr.product_name,round(sum(ii.line_total_price),2) as tot 
from city ci ,customer cu,invoice i,invoice_item ii,product pr where ci.id=cu.city_id and cu.id=i.customer_id and i.id=ii.invoice_id and ii.product_id=pr.id
group by ci.city_name,pr.product_name
order by tot desc,ci.city_name, pr.product_name
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).